# What are the assumptions that we make when we compute KL Divergence between two distributions?

Tags: probability, distributions, kullback-leibler

Let us assume that we compute the KL Divergence between p and q. Is it necessary that both p and q belong to the exponential family of distributions. Moreover, is it necessary, that both p and q should be of the same family, i.e. either both should be gaussian, or both should be dirichlet and so on.

Comment: No. In computing KL divergence between two distributions, you do not need to make these assumptions. The most you *might* need to assume is that $p$ and $q$ have the same support, but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: What is meant by support here?

Comment: The values for which the densities $p$ and $q$ take positive values. For example, the support of a Normal distribution is $\mathbb{R}$, the support of a Gamma distribution is $(0,\infty)$, the support of a Beta distribution is $(0,1)$ etc.

Comment: Can someone comment how to compute distance between function when they dont have a common support? or KL divergence if you want to be specific. Generic answer is appreciated.

Comment: Reference would be helpful for KL divergence in extended form when support is different.

Answer (score 1):

KL divergence will always exist when P & Q have same support. They donot have to be in same family of distributions. Infact most of the times Q in unimodal and P is not(the idea of approximate inference).

A class of inference which gives nice examples for how complex P and Q would be [Variational Inference](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/variational-inference-i.pdf) which is essentially an approximate inference method (Also common in literature and implementations available for many methods). For example, you could look at [LDA](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf) (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) inference and learning ( detailed derivations can be found in appendix).

P.S. I am not aware of any extended form when support for P and Q do not match.

Answer (score 0):

To be really technical about it, KL(p,q) is finite whenever q has a Radon-Nikodim (I might be wrong on the spelling here) compared to p. In english, if for all events A, p(A)>0 implies q(A>0)

Otherewise, it is well-defined as infinite